# Performing validations for the form

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I am using Jquery and cakephp for my application.

I am having  a form created in my page using `$form->create`. The form contains many fields which the user will fill and on submitting, the data is saved by

```
function submit($id = null)
{
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value):

        $this->data['Result']['form_id']=$id;//form id
        $this->data['Result']['label']=$key;//this is the fieldname
    $this->data['Result']['value']=$value;//fieldvalue  

endforeach;

    $this->Session->setFlash('Your entry has been submitted.');
  }
```

Now I want to perform validations in the Form like whether all the field values have been filled. If not filled, it must show an alert or a message asking the user to fill the appropriate field. How do I do that?

One more suggestion needed: which would be better, validation on the client side or the server side?

Comment: Why are you using $_POST id you're creating forms with the FormHelper?

Comment: *If*, I meant to say if, not id..

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP has built in validation: check out the documentation [here](http://book.cakephp.org/view/125/Data-Validation). You basically tell it the various conditions each attribute of your model must satisfy ("is not empty", etc.). These are then checked automatically when you call the `save` method - so be sure to check for the return value of that function call.

An example from the linked documentation page:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'User';
    var $validate = array(
        'login' => 'alphaNumeric',
        'email' => 'email',
        'born' => 'date'
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Ya but the form fields will change for every form , SO in tat sense how can i keep like email,login and all.

Comment: Use the beforeValidate() method in the model to dynamically change $validates accordingly. Set a hidden field (or use Session) to tell beforeValidate how to change validates for different forms.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/682/beforeValidate